# Why does GCC copy object for each comparison in `std::ranges::max`?

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, clang, std-ranges

Consider the following example ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hcz3TzYK7)):

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>

struct A
{
    A() {}
    A( const A& ) { std::cout << "Copy\n"; }
    A( A&& ) noexcept { std::cout << "Move\n"; }

    A& operator=(const A&) { std::cout << "Copy assigned\n"; return *this; }
    A& operator=( A&& ) noexcept { std::cout << "Move assigned\n"; return *this; }

    int x = 10;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> vec( 10 );
    std::cout << "Init\n";
    std::cout << std::ranges::max( vec, [] ( const auto& a, const auto& b ) { std::cout << "cmp" << std::endl; return a.x < b.x; } ).x;
}
```

This program compiled with GCC 13.2 (even with [`-O3`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-O3) optimization turned on) produces the following output:

```
Init
Copy
Copy
cmp
Copy
cmp
Copy
cmp
Copy
cmp
Copy
cmp
Copy
cmp
Copy
cmp
Copy
cmp
Copy
cmp
10
```

But compiled with Clang 17 (with `-stdlib=libc++` and any optimization level), it performs no copying at all (except for the returned value, as I understand it):

```
Init
cmp
cmp
cmp
cmp
cmp
cmp
cmp
cmp
cmp
Copy
10
```

If `A` has a costly copy-constructor, this difference will drastically decrease performance.

Is there a reason why GCC has this implementation of `std::ranges::max` or is it a bug?

Comment: My next step would be is to set a breakpoint in the copy constructor, then try to figure out where in the templates it gets invoked, and why.

Comment: Well, you were asking for a "why", which I can't give -- I'm not an STL wizard to come up with an explanation right away. I can, however, come up with a solution: `std::cout << std::ranges::max_element( vec, [] ( const auto& a, const auto& b ) { std::cout << "cmp" << std::endl; return a.x < b.x; } )->x;`

Comment: Try making the move constructor `noexcept`.  The std containers need to play safe when moving stuff.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @RichardCritten I updated the question taking your comments into account. It still produces the same output.

Comment: BTW: With the Microsoft C++ compiler I almost get the second output, but the `Copy` is replaced by `Move`.

Comment: The GCC output makes me think `max` is getting implmeneted like `max(1st_elem, max(2nd_elem, max(3rd_elem, max(...))))`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's, what I presume, a "bug" in the gcc implementation and I wrote a [bugreport](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=112349).

LLVM has two versions inside the `operator()` overload being used:

```cpp
auto __first = std::ranges::begin(__r);
auto __last = std::ranges::end(__r);

_LIBCPP_ASSERT(__first != __last, "range must contain at least one element");

if constexpr (std::ranges::forward_range<_Rp>) {
    // MY COMMENT: This is what's actually being used:

    auto __comp_lhs_rhs_swapped = [&](auto&& __lhs, auto&& __rhs) {
        return std::invoke(__comp, __rhs, __lhs);
    };
    return *std::ranges::min_element(std::move(__first),
                                        std::move(__last),
                                        __comp_lhs_rhs_swapped, __proj);
} else {
    std::ranges::range_value_t<_Rp> __result = *__first;
    while (++__first != __last) {
        if (std::invoke(__comp, std::invoke(__proj, __result),
                                std::invoke(__proj, *__first)))
            __result = *__first;
    }
    return __result;
}
```

.. but it doesn't matter if I disable the version currently being used and instead use the `while` loop. It still doesn't copy.

Now for the `operator()` overload in GCC's case:

```cpp
auto __first = std::ranges::begin(__r);
auto __last = std::ranges::end(__r);

__glibcxx_assert(__first != __last);

auto __result = *__first;        
while (++__first != __last) {
    auto __tmp = *__first;
    if (std::__invoke(__comp, std::__invoke(__proj, __result),
                              std::__invoke(__proj, __tmp)))
        __result = std::move(__tmp);
}
return __result;
```

The copy is here:

```cpp
auto __tmp = *__first;
```

I assume it *should* be:

```
auto& __tmp = *__first;
```

because with that change, it doesn't copy anymore.

Note: I've added `std::` and `std::ranges::` in a couple of places to be able to use the algorithms outside their natural habitat which is inside the standard library implementations.

---

**Update**

The bug is now confirmed. [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely) also replied:

> > *[me]* `auto& __tmp = *__first;`
>
> *[JW]* That won't compile for a `move_iterator` or a proxy reference. I think `auto&&` would be OK.
>
> > *[me]* ...or just supplying `*__first` to `std::__invoke`
>
> *[JW]* I think that would be OK too.

So, if his initial assessment is correct, it should be a low hanging fruit for someone to pick and we can hope for a fix in a near release.

Comment: `auto& __tmp = *__first;` won't copy indeed, but I assume iterator is not required to return referencable value. It could possibly return a temporary. I think `std::ranges::range_value_t<_Rp>` accounts exactly for this in LLVM.

Comment: @Andrew That was my first instinct too but just making it `std::ranges::range_value_t<_Range> __tmp = *__first;` had no effect. I didn't dig deeper there.

Comment: @Andrew I've now written a bugreport. Let's see what comes out of that.